# Can I connect a non NAS marketed external hard drive to this router and access the files over the network?

Tags: wireless-networking, external-hard-drive

I was looking at purchasing the "LINKSYS EA7500 MAX-STREAM™ AC1900 MU-MIMO GIGABIT ROUTER" router (http://www.linksys.com/gb/p/P-EA7500/) and noticed it had a USB 3.0 port on it.

Can I attach a "normal" (i.e. not a NAS) external hard drive such as the "WD ELEMENTS PORTABLE" (https://www.wdc.com/products/portable-storage/wd-elements-portable.html) and still access those files over the network?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What makes you think it needs to be a "NAS drive", and that a 'regular' USB-attached drive wouldn't work?   Nothing in the router's spec say it needs to be a "NAS drive"....

Comment: how is that unclear? that is exactly what I was asking! I want to know if a regular USB attached drive would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. 
It will work with any consumer USB3 hard-drive.
In fact the feature is specifically designed to be used with such drives.

NAS marketed hard-drives have more to do with the suitability for use in a RAID setup inside a dedicated NAS device.
"NAS" hard-drives are always sold as bare drives. They don't come with a USB enclosure as that makes no sense whatsoever. You can put one inside a USB enclosure, but you won't get any benefits. It just is more expensive than using a standard hard-drive.

Comment: Awesome thanks Tonny - I guess that means that the network file server software (samba or whatever) is actually held within the router itself?

Comment: @NickMeldrum Yes. Most cases the router runs a stripped down version of either Linux or VNX. On top of that there is Samba and often also AFP (Apple Fileserver Protocol)